# Android - How to get the user current location every time based on sim Network

Tags: android, networking, geocoding, locationlistener

I want to get the user's current location (latitude and longitude) always using Sim-based network only, not by using any other networks (like WiFi, Mobile Data, GPS and other Network and even all these are in Disabled mode in mobile). Not necessarily exact location but even approximate location. Is there any possibility to get it. If any of you can explain and include code; I searched in Google but did not get the correct related answer...

Thanks in Advance