# can't get the city name of my current location in my country, android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android application.In my application I want to get the city name of my current location, but I have a problem in my country. If I used Google Geode API it doesn't recognize it, eg: when I try this query which must return information about my location using lat and longitude; it doesn't work.

this is the query : `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.3117,35.0272&sensor=true`

also when I use this code, I get the address= null:

```
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(this);
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 5);

                    Log.e("get adderess", addresses + "");
                    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

                        System.out.print(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    }

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

the problem is in my country ONLY :(

any help how to solve it ??

Comment: Use my code. View my answer. It works :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301625/android-how-to-get-the-user-current-location-every-time-based-on-sim-network/20301727#20301727

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me fine.It gives you city name and country name on behalf of your latitude and longitude.But on some places it didn't gives you the city name i.e Asia etc(some places).

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    Address address;
    List<Address> list;
    list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);//33.64600, 72.96115
    address = list.get(0);
    String cityname =  address.getLocality();
    String countryname =   address.getCountryName();        
    Log.d("cityname",cityname.toString());
    Log.d("countryname",countryname.toString());
```

Also Please add the following uses-permission node within the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: my country is : Palestine

Comment: Actually now i know what your problem is.The code is fine.When you input lat,lng (32.3117,35.0272) on [link](http://maps.google.com) you can't find any description of the place i.e place name, city name etc.It only shows you Address as description.So thats why it doesn't shows up in your code also.

Comment: Sorry bro i cant know anymore.Well i think Google may be biased and intentionally don't mention your country's name etc.Try changing the GPS coordinates around the country and figure out whether it is with your current location or with your whole country.If you still need any help just comment here.Best of luck :)

Comment: thanks a lot, and I am a Girl :)
the problem is in my whole country

Comment: I am using openstreetmap instead of Google, but it is confusing, it sometimes returns a city name, road, and town

Comment: Haven't tried open street map.But using Google you cant achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

have u encoded your URL?
one needs to encode and decode the url while sending and receiving by http request

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting null as your city, or any other values

Then try this code, it worked fine for me

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(YourActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> addresses  = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String country = addresses.get(1).getCountryName();
        String city = addresses.get(1).getLocality();
```

You are getting null for the first values

In this code, instead of getting the first values, you will get the second one, so instead of typing `addresses.get(0)` you will type `addresses.get(1)`