# GPS Locater error on Android phone

Tags: java, android, gps

I've created an application in which, when I click a button, it gives me my gps coordinates. In the simulator it works with no problem, but when I've tried it on a mobile phone a had the next 2 scenarios: when I had the GPS activated, nothing happened, and when i didn't had the GPS connected, it said "Gps Disabled"

Here is my code so far:
This is the .java file: (Saver.java):

```
package com.example.lifesaver;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Saver extends Activity {

Button b;

Location newLocation = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


// We use LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);


b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
      if (newLocation != null) {

          String Text = "Current location is: " + "Latitud = "
                  + newLocation.getLatitude() + "Longitud = "
                  + newLocation.getLongitude();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text,
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
}); 
}

//MyLocationListener class

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        newLocation = loc;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
}
```

And the .xml file(activity_saver.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Saver" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/circle" 
android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, i've added this in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to turn on GPS programmatically ?

It won't work above versions 4.0. You have to turn it on manually.

Use my code :-

[Android - How to get the user current location every time based on sim Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301625/android-how-to-get-the-user-current-location-every-time-based-on-sim-network/20301727#20301727)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the GPS to get a fix. onLocationChanged may not be triggered for several minutes from a cold start. If you are inside a building you may **never** get a fix. There is no such facility as 'get my position via GPS immediately'.